# How to remove a string from an array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I want to remove a string from an array list. For instance one row would be `[290..2, 310.1, 310.0]`. In this case the string would be `290..2`. So basically I have a lot of data which is entered manually and I want to omit the entire row which contains a wrong input such as the example I have shown. Are there any existing functions I can use to fix this issue?

Comment: What is `290..2`? That's not a thing in Python. Can you please show actual runnable code with a [mre]?

Comment: Do you mean a numpy array or a regular python list?

Comment: Do you want to search specifically the string `290..2`, or any string that contains `..`?

Comment: `[290..2, 310.1, 310.0]` is not a valid list. Did you mean `["290..2", "310.1", "310.0"]` or `["290..2", 310.1, 310.0]` or something else?

Comment: @Barmar I want to search anything that might be a string in my array so any value that has .. or even ... etc and omit that row which has a string.

Comment: @001 Ideally I would fix it and get `[290.2, 310.1, 310.0]`, however another go around would be to omit that row completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited based on your feedback. Sounds like you might have a list of lists? Still not sure if it's a list or array based on your code though. Does this help at all?

```
list_1 = [[1,2,"1..1"], [1,2, 1], [1,2,1], [1,2,"1..1"],[1,2,"1..1"], [1,2, 1]]

list_reversed =  reversed(list_1)

len_list_1 = len(list_1)

for ind, sublist in enumerate(list_reversed):
    x_t = [isinstance(a, str) for a in sublist ] 
    if any(x_t):
        print(f"string here!! - {sublist}")
        list_1.pop(len_list_1-(ind+1))
    else: 
        print(f"No string here - {sublist}")

print(f"\nResult: {list_1}")
```

Result is as follows (i.e. remove any sublist containing a str):

```
[[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Did not work for my array it was still there after I tried it

Comment: Justin, I amended this to try to handle your rank-2 data format. Does this work?

Comment: When I tried to run the code I got a syntax error `list_reversed =  np.reversed(list_1)`

Comment: Hi Justin. I didn't use any numpy in my code above, just lists. Can you try the code without modifying it? Try `reversed` (instead of `np.reversed` )

Comment: Sorry my mistake don't know why I included `np.` I tried to run your code as is and got a syntax error in this line `list_reversed =  reversed(list_1)` obviously in my case `list_1` contains my data.

Comment: Justin, can you convert your array to a list using the `list()` function (before running `reversed()` ) and see if this works

Answer (score 0):

from what i could understand you want to filter out the string from a list

```
list = ["2...7",1,2,3]
list2 = []
for x in list:
    if not type(x) == str:
        list2.append(x)
    else: ## not required but i just did it for confirmation ##
        pass
print (list2)
```

And if you don't want to create a second list you can also use this method

```
list = ["2...7",1,2,3]
for x in list:
    if type(x) == str:
        list.remove(x)
print (list)
```

this was the **output** [ for both methods ]

> [1, 2, 3]

Comment: I actually have an array and in one of the columns there is a row which contains a string. I would like to completely omit that row
Example: 
`y = [889 104.0 12.5]
 [892..6 104.9 12.5]
 [893.6 104.6 12.6]`
I want to completely remove the 2nd row due to the `892..6` which is seen as a string when I eventually have to plot

Comment: @Justin `892..6` is not a possible element of the list. If it's a string, there should be quotes around it. Are there quotes around all the elements?

Comment: @Barmar There are not any quotes that is why I was confused as to why I got to the plots to be told I have an error due to a string being there

Comment: Can you edit the question and show how you're creating the array? I'm unable to create a numpy array that contains `892..6` without using strings, and when I print the array the quotes are shown.

Comment: @Justin e.g. `np.array([[1.2, '192..6'], [3.4, 5.6]])` prints as `[['1.2' '192..6']
 ['3.4' '5.6']]`

Comment: @Barmar No there are not any quotes, I am processing data that was given in an excel sheet and one of cells to be exact had the value '891..2' I realised that it was there when I came to plot and was given the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '891..2'` . So I just need to remove that row containing that cell

Comment: How are you turning the Excel sheet into an array? Please SHOW THE CODE like I asked.

Comment: @Justin Note that all elements of a numpy array have the same dtype. If any of them cannot be interpreted as a number, it will be an array of strings. When you then try to plot it, that will try to convert them all to numbers, and you'll get that error. You can't filter the original array by datatype, since they're all strings. So you must do it by checking the contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just keep the float values in the list then this might help:

```
def float_values(lst):
    return [val for val in lst if isinstance(val, float)]
```

This function will check the list and will return a list with only valid float values.